# svn propedit in a noninteractive script

Tags: svn, shell, unix, post-commit

I need to edit a svn property on a file after a commit happened. Therefor I'd like to use a post-commit script.

Example:

I have a property called `export` with a value set to `test` when I commit a file called `example.ex`
After my commit succeeded I have a post-commit hook, that does some smart things (that doesn't matter to my question) and after finishing it needs to change (or delete) the property `export` to a new value like `succeeded`.

On command line I would use this:

```
svn propedit "export"  file:///svn/repositoryName/path/to/file/in/repository/example.ex
```

This will open my system editor `vi` and I will see the value `test`. I can change it to whatever I want and save and quit the file with vi commands like `:wq`

Subversion gives back a message like this

```
"svn-prop.tmp" 1L, 10C written
Set new value for property 'export' on file:///svn/repositoryName/path/to/file/in/repository/example.ex'
Committed revision 67.
```

So much so fine. But as I've said, I need that in a post-commit script, where I can't control vi (or am I wrong?).

So Subversion gives me the possibility to add a file to the command `propedit`. The file contains just the new value `succeeded`.

The new command should look like this:

```
svn propedit "export"  file:///svn/repositoryName/path/to/file/in/repository/example.ex --file /path/to/propertyValueFile/propValue.file
```

And here's the problem: the last command doesn't work. Again `vi` opens and I need to change my value manually. Why? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: okay, meanwhile I've realized that --file will use the content of this file as log message.

nevertheless, same problem: I need it in a script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution, that works for me.

```
svn propedit "export" file:///svn/repositoryName/path/to/file/in/repository/example.ex --file /data/svn/intranet/hooks/fileWithLogMessage --editor-cmd "echo succeeded >"
```

`--editor-cmd` gives another editor and I can outsmart propedit with `echo newValueForProp`.

And now it works like a charm.

--

Answer (score 0):

Try using `svn propset` rather than `svn propedit`. Using `propedit` *always* opens an external editor... that's what it's for.

Comment: No. That's not a solution, because svn propset doesn't work either, if the property is already set. But I've found the solution by myself. But thanks anyway.